# AWS Load Balancer HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, https

I am trying to use the AWS ELB service for SSL offloading. The problem is that, while HTTP goes smoothly through the load balancer, HTTPS somehow doesn't work and gives a "Your connection is not secure" in FireFox

This is the setup:

```
1 Load Balancer(for SSL offloading and to enable AWS shield (DDOS protection)) --> 1 EC2 server <--> 1 DB server
```

How I've configured it:

```
Load balancer with listener on port 80 and 443.
target group with ONLY port 80 enabled.
Security group with port 80 and 443 on both load balancer and EC2 instance.
```

Am I missing something?

NOTE: I've checked the documentation and almost seen all YouTube videos that are remotely related, to no avail.

Comment: Are you accessing the IP address or using a domain name?

Comment: Oh wauw... I used the public dns of the load balancer. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, are you using a domain ?

Have you set up ssl certificates ?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

Comment: Forgot about the whole domain thing... thanks anyway!